# best way of rendering more 3D models in three.js that not slow down page?

Tags: webgl, three.js

I am in the way of creating a 3D web game using threeJS library. This is a multi-player game that players are 3D human models in game, and I need to add a human 3D model for each player that enters the game. Additionally, I want to animate the humans while they walking, but the problem, here is that adding a 3D model and animating that for each player will slow down the game or maybe cause the browser to crash.

question: what is the better way of showing and animating the player's models that will not slow down the game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do extra work for free.

What you need to do instead is do some testing on a range of hardware and browsers, and find out how many players you can handle on the slowest platform you want to support. You can then limit the maximum number of players to that number.

More players also means more network bandwidth is required, you may run out of that before rendering performance becomes an issue.

Comment: You are right. but I don't want a very good-looking model for my players, can I simulate a 3D model using textures and effects, so I don't need to load a 3D model?

Comment: Yes. That's how Doom did its characters - a 2D sprite on a billboard.

Comment: Can you provide a link or describe it, that shows me how can I do this in three.js (or other libraries)?

Comment: Here's how to do it in XNA: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2011/01/12/spritebatch-billboards-in-a-3d-world.aspx